# How to send email as EML attachment with SendGrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, email-attachments, sendgrid-api-v3

I've got a webhook which is parsing emails sent by SendGrid's Inbound Parse, and if any error occurs with processing the email, I want to send the original email as an EML attachment to a notification email address.

I've been using [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to parse the `multipart/form-data` received by the webhook and I receive the full plain cleartext of the email contents itself. Everything is fine there.

When I go to send the email using [`@sendgrid/mail`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail) and set the original email as an EML attachment file, this is where I get issues.

I've tried a variety of content encodings and mimetypes, but haven't found one that works yet as a EML file. I've tried `text/plain`, `message/rfc822` and `application/octet-stream` with plain text (which results in error from SendGrid API), and `base64` encoded text.

In fact, it gets weirder. When I send the email attachment as `text/plain` with `filename` ending in `.txt`, everything seems to be good. When I download the attachment and rename to `.eml` then it views perfectly in my Mail app.

However, when I send the email attachment as `text/plain`, `message/rfc822` or `application/octet-stream` with `filename` ending in `.eml`, this is where I get inconsistencies. In the email I sent I can see that the filename now ends with `.eml.eml` and opening the file in my Mail app shows me base64 encoded text (decoding the text gives me the original email contents that I had to encode in order to allow the endpoint to send as an attachment). Viewing the file contents in a text editor looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
MIME-Version: 1.0

VGhpcyBpcyB3aGVyZSB0aGUgYmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgZW1haWwgdGV4dCBnb2Vz
```

My current conclusion is that the SendGrid `/v3/mail/send` API endpoint is treating attachments with `.eml` extension in the `filename` differently and encapsulating the base64-encoded contents within another `.eml` wrapper. It doesn't seem possible to set an attachment's `content` to a plain text string as I get a 400 Bad Request from the endpoint if its not base64 encoded.

I haven't been able to find any [official documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#folder-1803116a-attachments) about this particular behaviour on this endpoint. The closest I got was this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/722) (dated 2018), but it doesn't seem to solve my issue.